# How to do while loop when it comes to files and strings?

Tags: c, string, file, if-statement, while-loop

I am recently trying to write a code in which the program will show the derivative of a function using the product rule. The function can be either one of: `x^n`, `sin(a*x)` or `cos(a*x)`. As an example it can be a set of three functions, so the file may look like this:

```
x^7*sin(3.14*x) 
cos(4*x)*sin(5.2*x)
cos(2*x)*cos(8*x)
```

I wrote some local functions, such as

```
void derivcc ()
{
    double a, b;
    fscanf(f,"cos(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)",&a, &b);
    if (a<0 && b<0) 
        printf("%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)+%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)\n",
                -a,a,b,-b,b,a);

    else if (a<0 && b>0) 
        printf("%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)-%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)\n",
                -a,a,b,b,b,a);

    else if (a>0 && b<0) 
        printf("-%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)+%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)\n",
                a,a,b,-b,b,a);

    else
        printf("-%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)-%lfsin(%lf*x)*cos(%lf*x)\n", 
            a,a,b,b,b,a);
}
```

However, the issue that I am having is in the main function. I want to know how should I address the while loop, so the local functions can work. Here is the main:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE * f;
    char lines[50];
    f=fopen("function.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error with opening the file!/n");
        exit (1);
    }
    int c;
    fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), f); 
    char sin[]="sin";
    char cos[]="cos";
    char x[]="x^";
    char *checkc, *checks, *checkx;
    checkc = strstr(lines,cos);
    checks = strstr(lines,sin);
    checkx = strstr(lines, x);
    double a,b;


    while((c = getc(f)) != EOF) 
    {
        if (checks == NULL)
        {
            if (checkc == NULL)
            {
                derivxx();
            }
            else 
            {
                if (checkx==NULL)
                    derivcc();
                else 
                {
                    if (lines[0] == cos[0])
                        derivcx(); 
                    else
                        derivxc();
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (checkc == NULL && checkx == NULL)
            {
                derivss();
            }
            else 
            {
                if (checkc == NULL && checkx != NULL)/
                {   
                    if (lines[0]==sin[0])
                        derivsx();
                    else
                        derivxs(); 
                }
                else if (lines[0]==sin[0])
                    derivsc();
                else
                    derivcs();
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of `function.txt`? I'm not sure you are doing the parsing correctly.

Comment: the function.txt for now has 3 trial functions which are:
x^7*sin(3.14*x)
cos(4*x)*sin(5.2*x)
cos(2*x)*cos(8*x)

Comment: Each one one a line? Please edit your question and post that there.

Comment: OK, but I haven't done anything. If you've found a solution to your problem, consider posting your solution as an answer, so that people in the feature can see what solved the problem.

Comment: oh, what I meant was that I added the example of a function.txt, so it is clear to other readers. I did not solve the issue yet

Comment: `"Error with opening the file!/n"` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  It doesn't tell you what the error was, doesn't tell you which file it refers to, and is printed to the wrong stream.  Try `perror`.  eg `if( (f=fopen(path, mode)) == NULL) { perror(path); ... `

Comment: And not testing the return value from fscanf() is **always a bug**.

Comment: How should I test it? I am not sure if the fscanf is working properly itself, because I guess it is not ignoring the values inbetween

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got most of the code. You just need to rearrange it a little to make it work. Here's the code that you have:

```
int c;
fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), f); 
char sin[]="sin";
char cos[]="cos";
char x[]="x^";
char *checkc, *checks, *checkx;
checkc = strstr(lines,cos);
checks = strstr(lines,sin);
checkx = strstr(lines, x);
double a,b;

while((c = getc(f)) != EOF)
{ 

}
```

The code reads the first line and then gets some information about that line using the `strstr` function. Then the `while` loop starts reading one character at a time.

What needs to happen is the `while` loop needs to **read one line at a time**. And the `strstr` calls need to be **inside the `while` loop**. So the code should look like this:

```
char sin[]="sin";
char cos[]="cos";
char x[]="x^";
char *checkc, *checks, *checkx;
double a,b;

while(fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), f) != NULL)
{ 
   checkc = strstr(lines,cos);
   checks = strstr(lines,sin);
   checkx = strstr(lines, x);


}
```